# How do define read replicas in gorm postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am using golang in my application server and gorm as the ORM. I am using postgresql as the database in google cloud sql.

I created a 2 read replica's for postgres which are being used by the application server.

Previously, I used node.js and sequelize and there, I am able to define the read replicas as

```
    read: [
      { host: '8.8.8.8', username: 'anotherusernamethanroot', password: 'lolcats!' },
      { host: 'localhost', username: 'root', password: null }
    ],
    write: { host: 'localhost', username: 'root', password: null }
  },
```

However for gorm, I dont see any way to do that(in the documentation).

So, is there a way that I can define read replicas and gorm takes care of it.  If not, what is the best practice for this use case?

Comment: is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Now that Gorm V2 is out you can use the `dbresolver` plugin just for this use case. Replicating what you gave as an example would look like:

```golang
import (
  "gorm.io/gorm"
  "gorm.io/plugin/dbresolver"
  "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
)

db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open("host=localhost user=root"), &gorm.Config{})

db.Use(dbresolver.Register(dbresolver.Config{
    Replicas: []gorm.Dialector{
        postgres.Open("host=8.8.8.8 user=anotherusernamethanroot password=lolcats!"), 
        postgres.Open("host=localhost user=root"),
    },
    Policy: dbresolver.RandomPolicy{},
})
```

Check out the documentation: https://gorm.io/docs/dbresolver.html